# Query runs faster with EXPLAIN ANALYZE using parallel plan. Slows down and loses parallel workers without EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Postgres with DBeaver JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, dbeaver, postgresql-12, jdbc-postgres

I'm really puzzled by the following query:

```sql
explain analyze 
(with z as (
    select 1 as attraction
    ,1  as nd_attraction 
    , n.fc
    from (select pe_id,zo_id,co_id,value_num as dt 
            from rtpezocoav x --use view??
            where pe_id = 405 and ad_id = 4
            ) dt
    join calc_nodes n on n.co_id = dt.co_id and n.pe_id = 405  and n.se_id = 12
    join calc_zones z on dt.zo_id = z.zo_id and z.pe_id = 405 and z.se_id = 12
    left join calc_shopconcepts sh on sh.pe_id = 405 and sh.se_id = 12  and sh.sh_id = n.shop_concept and sh.ct_id = n.ct_id
    left join rtsepezobrav com on com.se_id = 12 and com.pe_id =  405 and com.zo_id = z.zo_id and com.br_id = n.br_id and com.ad_id = 308  --MV: switched to table instead of view
    join rtseperereav rere on rere.se_id = 12 and rere.pe_id =  405 and rere.re_id = z.re_id and rere.re2_id = n.re_id and rere.ad_id = 306 --MV: switched to table instead of view
)
    
    select sum(attraction::float), sum(nd_attraction::float) from z)
```

When I run it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` included, it finishes in < 0.5s and shows a clear parallel plan:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=455832.88..455832.89 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=397.581..397.581 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=455832.83..455832.84 rows=8 width=8) (actual time=397.355..399.729 rows=8 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 8
        Workers Launched: 7
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=455832.83..455832.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=382.349..382.349 rows=1 loops=8)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=9839.72..454742.30 rows=436213 width=0) (actual time=21.295..355.953 rows=627375 loops=8)
                    Hash Cond: ((z.re_id = rere.re_id) AND (n.re_id = rere.re2_id))
                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=9835.10..451732.66 rows=436213 width=8) (actual time=21.079..286.712 rows=627375 loops=8)
                          Hash Cond: (x.zo_id = z.zo_id)
                          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=4170.35..431738.52 rows=435194 width=12) (actual time=18.544..193.865 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                Hash Cond: (x.co_id = n.co_id)
                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on rtpezocoav x  (cost=1291.48..414863.71 rows=609897 width=8) (actual time=16.846..106.176 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                      Recheck Cond: (pe_id = 405)
                                      Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 104866
                                      Filter: (ad_id = 4)
                                      Heap Blocks: lossy=5558
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtpezocoav_pe_id_idx  (cost=0.00..71.69 rows=5315319 width=0) (actual time=3.754..3.754 rows=578560 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (pe_id = 405)
                                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2843.07..2843.07 rows=2864 width=12) (actual time=1.624..1.624 rows=616 loops=8)
                                      Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 416kB
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=126.56..2843.07 rows=2864 width=12) (actual time=0.572..1.348 rows=703 loops=7)
                                            Hash Cond: ((n.shop_concept = (sh.sh_id)::double precision) AND (n.ct_id = sh.ct_id))
                                            ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on calc_nodes n  (cost=122.19..2813.20 rows=2864 width=24) (actual time=0.439..0.789 rows=703 loops=7)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=53
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_calc_nodes_sepe  (cost=0.00..120.97 rows=4868 width=0) (actual time=0.580..0.580 rows=4924 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=4.33..4.33 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=3 loops=7)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_calc_shopconcepts_sepebr on calc_shopconcepts sh  (cost=0.27..4.33 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=3 loops=7)
                                                        Index Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                        Heap Fetches: 0
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=5551.19..5551.19 rows=9085 width=8) (actual time=2.405..2.405 rows=2721 loops=8)
                                Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1184kB
                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on calc_zones z  (cost=539.91..5551.19 rows=9085 width=8) (actual time=0.657..2.484 rows=5442 loops=4)
                                      Recheck Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=407
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_calc_zones_sepe  (cost=0.00..534.46 rows=21804 width=0) (actual time=2.351..2.351 rows=21768 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=4.48..4.48 rows=9 width=8) (actual time=0.080..0.080 rows=9 loops=8)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Index Only Scan using rtseperereav_unique on rtseperereav rere  (cost=0.28..4.48 rows=9 width=8) (actual time=0.057..0.060 rows=9 loops=8)
                                Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 306))
                                Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 3.801 ms
Execution Time: 399.879 ms
```

I also see 7 cores firing up briefly. However, when I run the query without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, it takes 2.5s and only 1 core is used.

Auto-explain in my database logs shows the same query plan but:

```
Workers Planned: 8; Workers Launched: 0
```

What could cause this ?

Below are my settings. I basically did the following:

```
set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8;
set parallel_setup_cost = 0;--1000
set parallel_tuple_cost = 0;
ALTER TABLE rtpezocoav SET (parallel_workers = 8);
```

These are my settings:

```
allow_system_table_mods off
application_name    DBEAVER - Mathias Versichele
archive_cleanup_command 
archive_command pgbackrest --stanza=main archive-push %p
archive_mode    on
archive_timeout 0
array_nulls on
authentication_timeout  1min
auto_explain.log_analyze    on
auto_explain.log_buffers    off
auto_explain.log_format text
auto_explain.log_level  log
auto_explain.log_min_duration   2s
auto_explain.log_nested_statements  on
auto_explain.log_settings   off
auto_explain.log_timing on
auto_explain.log_triggers   off
auto_explain.log_verbose    off
auto_explain.sample_rate    1
autovacuum  on
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor 0.1
autovacuum_analyze_threshold    50
autovacuum_freeze_max_age   200000000
autovacuum_max_workers  3
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age 400000000
autovacuum_naptime  1min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay    2ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit    -1
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor  0.2
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold 50
autovacuum_work_mem -1
backend_flush_after 0
backslash_quote safe_encoding
bgwriter_delay  200ms
bgwriter_flush_after    512kB
bgwriter_lru_maxpages   100
bgwriter_lru_multiplier 2
block_size  8192
bonjour off
bonjour_name    
bytea_output    hex
check_function_bodies   on
checkpoint_completion_target    0.5
checkpoint_flush_after  256kB
checkpoint_timeout  5min
checkpoint_warning  30s
client_encoding UTF8
client_min_messages notice
cluster_name    
commit_delay    0
commit_siblings 5
config_file /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql.conf
constraint_exclusion    partition
cpu_index_tuple_cost    0.005
cpu_operator_cost   0.0025
cpu_tuple_cost  0.01
cursor_tuple_fraction   0.1
data_checksums  off
data_directory  /var/lib/pgsql/12/data
data_directory_mode 0700
data_sync_retry off
DateStyle   ISO, MDY
db_user_namespace   off
deadlock_timeout    1s
debug_assertions    off
debug_pretty_print  on
debug_print_parse   off
debug_print_plan    off
debug_print_rewritten   off
default_statistics_target   100
default_table_access_method heap
default_tablespace  
default_text_search_config  pg_catalog.english
default_transaction_deferrable  off
default_transaction_isolation   read committed
default_transaction_read_only   off
dynamic_library_path    $libdir
dynamic_shared_memory_type  posix
effective_cache_size    4GB
effective_io_concurrency    1
enable_bitmapscan   on
enable_gathermerge  on
enable_hashagg  on
enable_hashjoin on
enable_indexonlyscan    on
enable_indexscan    on
enable_material on
enable_mergejoin    on
enable_nestloop on
enable_parallel_append  on
enable_parallel_hash    on
enable_partition_pruning    on
enable_partitionwise_aggregate  off
enable_partitionwise_join   off
enable_seqscan  on
enable_sort on
enable_tidscan  on
escape_string_warning   on
event_source    PostgreSQL
exit_on_error   off
external_pid_file   
extra_float_digits  3
force_parallel_mode off
from_collapse_limit 8
fsync   on
full_page_writes    on
geqo    on
geqo_effort 5
geqo_generations    0
geqo_pool_size  0
geqo_seed   0
geqo_selection_bias 2
geqo_threshold  12
gin_fuzzy_search_limit  0
gin_pending_list_limit  4MB
hba_file    /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf
hot_standby on
hot_standby_feedback    off
huge_pages  try
ident_file  /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_ident.conf
idle_in_transaction_session_timeout 0
ignore_checksum_failure off
ignore_system_indexes   off
integer_datetimes   on
IntervalStyle   postgres
jit on
jit_above_cost  100000
jit_debugging_support   off
jit_dump_bitcode    off
jit_expressions on
jit_inline_above_cost   500000
jit_optimize_above_cost 500000
jit_profiling_support   off
jit_provider    llvmjit
jit_tuple_deforming on
join_collapse_limit 8
krb_caseins_users   off
krb_server_keyfile  FILE:/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/krb5.keytab
lc_collate  en_US.UTF-8
lc_ctype    en_US.UTF-8
lc_messages en_US.UTF-8
lc_monetary en_US.UTF-8
lc_numeric  en_US.UTF-8
lc_time en_US.UTF-8
listen_addresses    *
lo_compat_privileges    off
local_preload_libraries 
lock_timeout    0
log_autovacuum_min_duration -1
log_checkpoints off
log_connections off
log_destination stderr,csvlog
log_directory   log
log_disconnections  off
log_duration    off
log_error_verbosity verbose
log_executor_stats  off
log_file_mode   0600
log_filename    postgresql-%a.log
log_hostname    off
log_line_prefix 
log_lock_waits  off
log_min_duration_statement  1s
log_min_error_statement error
log_min_messages    notice
log_parser_stats    off
log_planner_stats   off
log_replication_commands    off
log_rotation_age    1d
log_rotation_size   0
log_statement   none
log_statement_stats off
log_temp_files  -1
log_timezone    Europe/Berlin
log_transaction_sample_rate 0
log_truncate_on_rotation    on
logging_collector   on
maintenance_work_mem    2GB
max_connections 500
max_files_per_process   1000
max_function_args   100
max_identifier_length   63
max_index_keys  32
max_locks_per_transaction   1500
max_logical_replication_workers 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers    4
max_parallel_workers    8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather 8
max_pred_locks_per_page 2
max_pred_locks_per_relation -2
max_pred_locks_per_transaction  64
max_prepared_transactions   0
max_replication_slots   10
max_stack_depth 2MB
max_standby_archive_delay   30s
max_standby_streaming_delay 30s
max_sync_workers_per_subscription   2
max_wal_senders 3
max_wal_size    3GB
max_worker_processes    8
min_parallel_index_scan_size    512kB
min_parallel_table_scan_size    8MB
min_wal_size    80MB
old_snapshot_threshold  -1
operator_precedence_warning off
parallel_leader_participation   on
parallel_setup_cost 0
parallel_tuple_cost 0
password_encryption md5
plan_cache_mode auto
plpgsql.check_asserts   on
plpgsql.extra_errors    none
plpgsql.extra_warnings  none
plpgsql.print_strict_params off
plpgsql.variable_conflict   error
port    5433
post_auth_delay 0
pre_auth_delay  0
primary_conninfo    
primary_slot_name   
promote_trigger_file    
quote_all_identifiers   off
random_page_cost    4
recovery_end_command    
recovery_min_apply_delay    0
recovery_target 
recovery_target_action  pause
recovery_target_inclusive   on
recovery_target_lsn 
recovery_target_name    
recovery_target_time    
recovery_target_timeline    latest
recovery_target_xid 
restart_after_crash on
restore_command 
row_security    on
search_path beobank20_predict
segment_size    1GB
seq_page_cost   1
server_encoding UTF8
server_version  12.2
server_version_num  120002
session_preload_libraries   
session_replication_role    origin
shared_buffers  40GB
shared_memory_type  mmap
shared_preload_libraries    auto_explain
ssl off
ssl_ca_file 
ssl_cert_file   server.crt
ssl_ciphers HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL
ssl_crl_file    
ssl_dh_params_file  
ssl_ecdh_curve  prime256v1
ssl_key_file    server.key
ssl_library OpenSSL
ssl_max_protocol_version    
ssl_min_protocol_version    TLSv1
ssl_passphrase_command  
ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload  off
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on
standard_conforming_strings on
statement_timeout   0
stats_temp_directory    pg_stat_tmp
superuser_reserved_connections  3
synchronize_seqscans    on
synchronous_commit  on
synchronous_standby_names   
syslog_facility local0
syslog_ident    postgres
syslog_sequence_numbers on
syslog_split_messages   on
tcp_keepalives_count    9
tcp_keepalives_idle 7200
tcp_keepalives_interval 75
tcp_user_timeout    0
temp_buffers    8MB
temp_file_limit -1
temp_tablespaces    
TimeZone    Europe/Brussels
timezone_abbreviations  Default
trace_notify    off
trace_recovery_messages log
trace_sort  off
track_activities    on
track_activity_query_size   16kB
track_commit_timestamp  off
track_counts    on
track_functions none
track_io_timing off
transaction_deferrable  off
transaction_isolation   read committed
transaction_read_only   off
transform_null_equals   off
unix_socket_directories /var/run/postgresql, /tmp
unix_socket_group   
unix_socket_permissions 0777
update_process_title    on
vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor   0.1
vacuum_cost_delay   0
vacuum_cost_limit   200
vacuum_cost_page_dirty  20
vacuum_cost_page_hit    1
vacuum_cost_page_miss   10
vacuum_defer_cleanup_age    0
vacuum_freeze_min_age   50000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age 150000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age 5000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age   150000000
wal_block_size  8192
wal_buffers 16MB
wal_compression off
wal_consistency_checking    
wal_init_zero   on
wal_keep_segments   0
wal_level   replica
wal_log_hints   off
wal_receiver_status_interval    10s
wal_receiver_timeout    1min
wal_recycle on
wal_retrieve_retry_interval 5s
wal_segment_size    16MB
wal_sender_timeout  1min
wal_sync_method fdatasync
wal_writer_delay    200ms
wal_writer_flush_after  1MB
work_mem    1280MB
xmlbinary   base64
xmloption   content
zero_damaged_pages  off
```

The database is on Linux (centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64).

Comment: Where are you running the query in each case?

Comment: I'm using DBeaver as a client for both queries, if that's what you're asking. Just found https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAD4o9TTi2Tny54nYVrf%3DfGdw4Yn7556S9w7eTwwfTo-dXejELQ%40mail.gmail.com, where someone is confronted with same issue but the message thread seems to stop short of a solution.

Comment: Also, auto-explain in my database logs shows the same query plan but: Workers Planned: 8; Workers Launched: 0

Comment: Not sure where you are getting the `2.5s`, but I'm going to guess it is at/in DBeaver. Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Oh. The 0.5s I took from the explain analyze output (execution time), the 2.5s is the time until I see the actual result (but it's just one record, so don't think network is playing a role). Database is on Linux (centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64) server.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean seeing result in DBeaver. In that case you are probably seeing the effect of GUI processing/handling. Try the bare query in psql with \timing set and see what you get.

Comment: Psql does work consistently, really weird...

Comment: Well DBeaver uses JDBC to connect and as I remember the Postgres JDBC driver does not use the libpq library, whereas `psql` does. Wondering if this is the issue or whether the JDBC driver being used is up to date with the changes in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible explanations for 0 workers being launched when 8 were planned:

1. All available parallel workers (`max_parallel_workers`) are being used. This is the likely explanation given that even with the fast plan you are showing, only 7 out of 8 planned workers could be launched.
2. You are running into one of the obstacles shown in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html).

Comment: As @adrianklaver mentioned, I tried to run the same query in psql with \timing. There, I do get the parallel execution I'm looking for. So in psql it consistently works, in DBeaver it doesn't... Is there any reason I could be seeing this behaviour ? Our web application calls SQL from PHP, and I hope we don't run into the same issue there.

Answer (score 0):

So, DBeaver using JDBC driver was the issue here. From now on, I'll measure performance in psql. Thx @adrianklaver.

Comment: The JDBC driver itself is not the reason. Do you limit the number of rows from within DBeaver? https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/client-performance-considerations/